# Two Rabbi Akivas?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rabbis

The gemara, in Ketubot 38b, resolves a contradiction between a mishna and a baraita by postulating the existence of a second person named Rabbi Akiva. Is there any reference, outside of this particular sugya, to this second Rabbi Akiva?

Comment: #PTIJ http://techeiles.org/viewer.php?filename=debate%2F%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%93%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F%2F%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A1+%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F+-+A+satirical+response+www.techeiles.org+.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were not two Rabi Akivas. What the Gemara is saying is there were two Tana'im with different opinions as to what Rabi Akiva actually said. One presented his version in a Mishna, and one presented his version in Baraisa.

> קשיא דר''ע אדר' עקיבא תרי תנאי ואליבא דר''ע בשלמא ר''ע דמתני' לא אתיא ג''ש ומפקא ליה לקרא מפשטיה לגמרי אלא לר''ע דברייתא אתיא גזירה שוה ומפקא מפשטיה לגמרי

And later on again a reference to this resolution:

> וקמיפלגי בפלוגתא דר''ע דמתניתין ורבי עקיבא דברייתא.

Comment: Thank you - I realised my mistake after posting this, but since you have written it out I won't delete it as I'd intended, but give you the points instead :)

Comment: Thanks;) And now that I know you are active today I might actually stop procrastinating and post a question I have that might need a historian's knowledge to answer.